# Set TYPO3_ACTIVE_FRAMEWORK_EXTENSIONS ENV variable in deploy process

Tags: continuous-integration, environment-variables, typo3

I'm using Gitlab CI to deploy TYPO3 projects onto a target server and I'm trying to remove the PackageStates.php from the git repository and generate it on the target server with EXT:typo3_console instead.
But I need to set the `TYPO3_ACTIVE_FRAMEWORK_EXTENSIONS` environment variable in order to have the necessary system extensions loaded.

How do I set this ENV variable?
What's a good way to store these information in my project to have it available in the deployment process? I could use Gitlab variables but I feel like this information should be included in the git repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set and use the env variable if you don't want to. You can just [require the TYPO3 core extensions](https://github.com/helhum/TYPO3-Distribution/blob/master/composer.json#L11-L26) you need in any package of your project and typo3_console will take care to populate the environment variable for you as needed during composer install time.

If you want to, you can however still override this env var from command line for individual calls.

EDIT: This feature has been integrated in typo3_console 3.3.0

Comment: After making sure to use a recent version of EXT:typo3_console this worked as expected. Defining the system extensions as dependencies is clean solution. Thank you!